# What is the usage of the "doctrine" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do you guys think the [doctrine](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctrine) is actually useful? If so what exactly should it be used on? Right now the questions tagged with it pretty much look like alphabet soup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think this tag is useful. If you want to tag a question [doctrine](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctrine) figure out what doctrine you are trying to talk about and then tag it with the appropriate elements or doctrinal tradition it comes from.

A generic doctrine tag is useless.

Answer (score 0):

[Using tags as a folksonomy](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153/bible-tag-too-general/174#174) as in Shog9's answer, I can see what I think are valid use cases for the tag. We might easily have an expert on different doctrines of justification, and to them the tag combination [justification](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/justification) [doctrine](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctrine) would help searching for interesting questions.

In the general case, tagging by the name of the doctrine won't work, as in all cases the different doctrines don't really have names but are rather characterized by the name of the church they are used in. We can't really have [lutheran-doctrine-of-justification](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lutheran-doctrine-of-justification).

Now, I will admit that my own use of the [doctrine](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctrine) tag has probably been bad, as has my use of tags in general. I will try to correct my ways.