# What translation are we interested in other than Bible translation?

Tags: discussion, tags

Or, in other words, is there any difference between [translation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) and [bible-translation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible-translation)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two [translation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) questions that might not fit into [bible-translation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible-translation).  One is about the [Book of Mormon](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4828/914) and the other is about the [Nicene Creed](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/354/what-is-the-distinction-between-consubstantial-and-one-in-being).

If [bible](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible) is a [useful tag](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153/bible-tag-too-general), we should set up a synonym:

- [bible-translation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible-translation) => [translation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation)

Then it will be possible to ask [translation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) questions about other texts or questions tagged [translation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) and [bible](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible).

Comment: I'm in favor of removing the [tag:bible-translation] tag for the [tag:translation] tag. I completely abhor hyphenated tags, especially when a tag exists for both words separately.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference at all: these tags should be merged.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple question about translating St. John of Damascus from Greek.

Should be able to see it now